# Is there a way to Stop or Quit parsing from within a DefaultHandler?

Tags: java, android, xmlreader

Is there a way to call a quit() function on an SAXParser or XMLReader?

The XML document is only updated every day or so, and I only want the full document to be read if the  element has changed.

Within my Default Handler:

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equals("pubDate")) {
        if (currentValue.equals(mPreviousPubDateValue)) {
                //exit parsing
        }
    } else {
        //keep on parsing
    }


}
```

The XML document is fairly large, and I'd like to be able to just quit it.  DefaultHandler doesn't have any built-ins for stopping the parsing.  I could also pass in a reference to the XMLReader, but it also doesn't have a method for stopping itself.

Thanks!

Comment: What about adding one break; inside the test for the date? You break the operation and show something that there is no new data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can throw the `SAXException` to stop parsing

you can use a subclass of it to ensure the parsing failed because of your decision and not a random parse exception

Answer (score 1):

(Please disregard following, of course you do this by throwing SAXException as in ratchetfreaks answer)

Interesting question --

I can think of one way --

If your parser is reading from an InputStream, create your own class that is a wrapper to another InputStream that just passes the calls through, until you set a flag on the wrapper.  With the flag set the wrapper indicates EOF to its caller.  Then, include a reference to this wrapper in your default handler and pass the wrapped stream to the parser.  When your handler determines it doesn't have to read anymore, it sets the flag on your wrapper, which sends an EOF to the parser, which stops parsing (and throws an exception, probably...)

This seems like a workable, although ugly solution.  Maybe someone has something else?

Comment: You can wrap the XMLReader instead of InputStream, of course.

Comment: I like your idea, but throwing an exception was a lot easier. :)